# User Mode Scheduler (UMS) returns ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: winapi, 64-bit, windows-10

I want to use the Windows **User-Mode Scheduler API** but every sample C or C++ I have found in the internet fails. Invariably I get ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.

My Computer is running Windows 10 Pro 64-bits in an x64 processor. I am using VS2015 and the application is an x64 console application.

Notably not every call fails, in the 4 samples I've tested either

1. EnterUmsSchedulingMode
2. CreateRemoteThreadEx

Fail with ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED. Those are necessary to get things going, but for example CreateUmsCompletionList or GetUmsCompletionListEvent do not.

The API is not trivial to use but I am having a hard time believing all of them are wrong.

I've debugged a bit what happens inside EnterUmsSchedulingMode and it seems that things go wrong when calling NtSetInformationThread inside RtlpAttachThreadToUmsCompletionList although of this I am less sure.

Here is [one](https://github.com/codepilot/UMS/blob/master/usm/usm.cpp)  and here is [another](https://lastsector.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/curious-case-of-user-mode-scheduling/) of the samples I've tried.

Comment: Have the same problem on Windows Server 2016 Data center edition. Did you managed to find the reason?

Comment: I have installed Windows Server 2012 R2 and now everything works. Unfortunately no clue to how get this work on Windows Server 2016 R2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on a pre-Ivy Bridge processor UMS will fail to work due to a potential security problem where an LDT is created on x64. The problem can be avoided with Ivy Bridge and a Windows 10 (and ostensibly Server 2016) update simply disables the UMS feature if the processor doesn't have access to the Ivy Bridge feature.

More info here: http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=340